# The method jsonPath() from the type ResponseBodyExtractionOptions refers to the missing type JsonPath

Tags: java, eclipse, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Getting compilation error

Added maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Added import
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

code is-

[Click on link to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9b2F.png)

Hover over the res.jsonPath(), it says - The method jsonPath() from the type ResponseBodyExtractionOptions refers to the missing type JsonPath.

I have tried to remove & add some dependencies and imports.

Comment: Why do you need that dependency? All jsonpath stuff is transitively joined by rest-assured dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `com.jayway.jsonpath` dependency and import `io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath` will fix your issue.